# How to display simple view page(xml file) just for seconds and then

Tags: android, splash-screen, setcontentview

My problem is something like splash-screen somehow, but i like to know is there any simpler way.

here is the scenario..

I like to display a simple XML file(android formatted Page) just for 2 second and then load other XML file(the main page).
I wondering is there anyway without creating class and long-complicated way.

let say the splash-screen file is "splash_screen.xml" and main page is "result.xml".

setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen) for 2 second, then it would be destroyed and setContentView(R.layout.result) will compiled. 
[psedocoded-way ;)]

Comment: You can try this : Try to set a timer in Activity A and once the timer ends call Activity B.

Comment: as i mentioned i dont like to create a activity for just loadin-displin' simple page(XML)..also i'm seeking a short way!

Comment: why do you want to load that page for 2 sec ,what is that page going to deal with in 2 sec ?

Comment: A i said splash-screen concept!

Comment: you can use dialog as well, just try for that

Comment: No way, the page has graphic-design!

Comment: What graphic design that page has ? please be specific because  its hard to understand what you are looking for and  its depedincies

Comment: Okay..the result page(result.xml) showing result of some calculation,when user press button to show this page i want to display other page(graphical loading shape,sth like loading shape) and other things and then display the result page..simple !!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:-

```
setContentView(R.layout.test2);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

This would work for you.

Comment: It's Not Worked, Just take 2 second to load "activity_main.xml"  !

Comment: Before loading the activity_main.xml, doesn't it loads the test2.xml ? because for me its working.

Comment: weird, for me it just take 2 sec to load activity_main . don't know, its not work for me, but Thank you.

Comment: well then I think you need to include the 2 class and then do those timer task or call the thread sleep method for 2 seconds. As this remains the only choice now.

Answer (score 0):

First, calling setContentView multiple times in one Activity is bad.

Well, it's not that complicated. You need your splash activity to be your opening activity.
Then, create a thread and start next activity after two seconds.

1) Main Class / Splash :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }finally{
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Result.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}



}
```

2) Second Class/ Result

```
public class Result extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result);
}


}
```

Finally, dont forget to add Result Activity in Manifest file

Comment: For me, it's not working. (my app load result.xml after pressing button)..i tried but got no result..anyway thanks.

Comment: Make sure MainActivity (activity which loads Splash in the Main activity in Manifest).It would be nice if you shared your code so that I can understand what you are trying to do.